# How to formulated a function that will give desired output

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I want to come up with a function that will result in numbers 7, 77, 777, 7777, and so on when imputing the natural numbers 1,2,3,.... I am not too sure how to go about creating such a formulate. I want to use this for Cantor Schroeder Bernstein problem I am trying to finish.

Comment: Can you not just say "the function that takes $n$ and outputs the number in base $10$ which has $n$ digits, all of them $7$"?

Comment: @PatrickStevens no I need to come up with an actual function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $10^n-1$ gives you $n$ nines.  (E.g. $10^3-1=999$).  What could you multiply that by to get $n$ sevens?

Comment: 7/9 would work. But does my approach work or should I pick to map to more numbers from my set S that I have listed?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, your approach would work, just mapping to the all 7s numbers.

Comment: Okay. Because I am using the CSB theorem so I need to show a function in both directions and this direction from the natural numbers to my set B is what I was having trouble finding a one to one function. I am trying to prove that the integers whose digits are 6,7,or 8 are denumerable.

Comment: @Sam This is an interesting question. But next time perhaps ask about what you really need to prove, not what you thought you needed to do to get there. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem .

Comment: @EthanBolker I did ask in my last question; this here was more of branching off from that now that I understand my question more

Answer (score 2):

For the 7, 77, 777 function, you could just use a geometric series.

$$F(x)=\sum_{i=1}^x{7*10^i} \\= 7 \sum_{i=1}^x{10^i}$$

Now using the geometric series, we have 
$$ F(x) = 7 \sum_{i=1}^x{10^i} \\ = \frac{7(10^{x+1}-1)}{9}.$$

Comment: But then x=0 would have to be used right?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd do it by recursion: let $f(1) = 7$, and then $f(n+1) = 10 f(n) + 7$. But if you want, you can write $$f(n) = 7 \times \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 10^i$$ which is manifestly a sum of a geometric series and so has a (messy) closed form.

EDIT: it's actually not that messy. Note that $111 = 999/9 = \frac{10^4 - 1}{9}$.